# Magento 2 youtube video not playing

Tags: magento, magento2

so I added the youtube api and then I tried to add a video to a product. In the backend everything seems to be fine. However on the product page the video is only shown as a static image, meaning I cannot play the video.

Does anybody know why there is only a thumbnail image instead of video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, bu you may be able to try to use a video you are sure can be embedded (a random video from youtube). Then you can exclude the problem is in Youtube settings or Magento2.

If it does not work maybe you have a specific error in console?

EDIT:

Did you do the usual:

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (-f)
- bin/magento cache:flush

?

Comment: I am pretty sure the videos that I chose can be embedded. In the backend, the video can be retrieved and played. however in the frontend it looks like this: https://globalvintagemedia.com/bianchi-specialissima-professionale-road-bike-1973

Comment: I did all of these, but no change.

Comment: found this possible fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6331#issuecomment-297681192